# $_SESSION is always null

Tags: php, api, session, wamp

I have 2 runtime environment simultanously :

- Front-end : Angular JS (localhost:4401) run with VS Code (ng serve)
- API : PHP run with WAMP (localhost) attached to a database.

For each call from my front-end to my API, I call session start like this :

(from "session.php" which is included in each *.php page)

```
session_start();

// Make sure we have a canary set
if (!isset($_SESSION['canary'])) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['canary'] = [
        'birth' => time(),
        'IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ];
}
```

I noticed that my $_SESSION variable has always a "null" value while executing code and it can't retrieve the session initially created (directory: wamp64\tmp).

Example of my call from Angular :

```
  checkLoginStatus(){
    // Used to check if stay logged in cookie is set - autologin...
    return this._http.get<loginResponse>(environment.api+"api/check_autologin.php").pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }
```

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens in the PHP code before `session_start();`

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.  `session_start();`  is the first line of each .php service. Each page starts with `include_once ("config/session.php");` and session.php starts with `session_start();`

Comment: I also noticed that $_SERVER is also empty...  After research, I feel that the problem comes from "global variables" but I don't know how to ensure this.

Comment: I assume you are using `http://` and not `file:///`

Comment: it seems unlikely that all your superglobals would be null or empty - where are you looking for these/generating the output?

Comment: @RiggsFolly : I'm using `http://`as much as possible. Am I right? Thanks :)

Comment: @imposterSyndrome Yes I also find that unlikely ... :s I'm sorry I don't have correctly understand your question. To introduce what I do with my code : first I call login.php => I created the session with an userId (viewable in my tmp directory)  and then when i call another service I check if I already have a session but the program don't find the existing session and create another one in the same directory!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a solution... but I've tested some tracks:
I tried to install uwamp instead of wamp ... same problem. Each call to my API generate a new session and I can't get only one session, I have as many session as I have called the app. My session directory is full of session files created with the different calls.
I think the best way is to share my phpinfo(). I already tried to change some params (particulary expiration time for cookie / session)
Thanks a lot

session

Registered save handlers : files user

session.auto_start : Off

session.cache_expire : 180

session.cache_limiter : nocache

session.cookie_domain : no value

session.cookie_httponly : no value

session.cookie_lifetime : 0

session.cookie_path : /

session.cookie_samesite : no value

session.cookie_secure : 1

session.gc_divisor : 1000

session.gc_maxlifetime : 1440

session.gc_probability : 1

session.lazy_write : On

session.referer_check : no value

session.save_handler : files

session.save_path : c:/wamp64/tmp

session.serialize_handler : php

session.sid_bits_per_charactersession.sid_length : 26

session.upload_progress.cleanup : On

session.upload_progress.enabled : On

session.upload_progress.freq : 1%

session.upload_progress.min_freq : 1

session.upload_progress.name : PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS

session.upload_progress.prefix :upload_progress_

session.use_cookies : 1

session.use_only_cookies : 1

session.use_strict_mode : 0

session.use_trans_sid : 0

Comment: It's normal to have an empty session, php uses a cookie to identify each user the cookie saved under localhost/yourapi basically your php server, but in your browser you are working with another server localhost:4401 which is another server where the cookie is not set, so each time you call session start, php will look for his cookie and can't found it, then he creates a new session and set a new cookie in localhost/yourapi, so you're complicating things, you should use Jwt instead to manage sessions your own

Comment: thanks, you're right. I had a problem with my proxy so the behaviour was exactly as you describe.

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if you want more explanations on working with php-JWT then i could post a detailed answer bellow